# discord.py | How to show ALL missing parameters in a command in the global error handler

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want to handle each of my commands in the discord.py's global error handler `on_command_error(ctx, error)` and what I want to do is to tell the user which parameters are missing, but discord.py (I think) only provides me with 1 parameter which is missing and I don't want to tell the user that, for instance in a purge command the missing argument is amount and then that another one is missing too in 2 messages, I just want to tell them all of the missing parameters.

So here's my code:

```
    async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, cmd.MissingRequiredArgument):
           arg = error.param.name
           await ctx.send(arg)
```

and above it unfortunately only shows 1 argument that is missing and the **error** variable doesn't provide any more info. 
So my question is is there any way to get all the arguments that are missing? If not in the discord.py library then maybe another?

Comment: Which library are you using to access the Discord API?

Comment: It's not a way to show missing arguments, but I'm trying to show the bot's help when I get a missing argument error. That's as close as I get to showing missing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

After researching some of it myself, discord.py raises an error only at the first parameter missing it spots. for example, if you have 3 parameters and you provide the first, it will raise an error saying that parameter (parameter's name) is missing. It doesn't do it for them all, but for the first parameter that is needed but is not found when the command is executed. Your code is just fine because it tells them the parameter missing. then, if they include it, it shows the next one. unfortunately, it can't be done otherwise as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own errors for this,

```py
class PurgeError(commands.CommandError):
   def __init__(self, text):
       self.text = text
   
   def __str__(): #used to get string of error
      return self.text

async def purge(ctx, args = None): #your command
  if args is None: #missing argument
      raise PurgeError("args is a required argument that is missing")

async def on_command_error(ctx, error): #error handler
  if isinstance(error, PurgeError):
      await ctx.send(error) #format error
```

### References:

- [Error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)
- [Command Error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandError)