# Procedural Discord.py command usage messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am implementing error messages into my `Discord.py` bot, where am using cogs to implement commands.

When a user incorrectly uses a command, for example passes no arguments into a command that requires them, I would like the bot to inform them of the correct usage of that specific command.

For example, here I have a simple cog `test.py`;

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client): 
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def test_command(self, ctx, arg1: str, arg2: int):
    msg = f"{arg1} and {arg2 + 5}"
    await ctx.reply(msg)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Test(client))
```

If the user uses the command incorrectly, for example types `!test_command foo`, I would like the bot to return a message along the lines of

> Correct usage: **!test_command <arg1> <arg2>**

How would I go about doing this? I would like to do it procedurally, and not have to pick from a list of pre-written usage help messages for each command.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Please note I already have the error checking logic in place. I am asking - in the event of an error triggering - how to automatically generate a message to inform the user on how to use the command.

Comment: Have you tried using the `on_command_error` listener?

Comment: @Dominik I already have the error checking logic in place. My question is asking how to automatically generate a usage message, with the argument names included in said message.

Comment: If you are not looking for a `discord.py` answer please remove the `discord.py` tag as there is only this method and I do not really get what else you want. You can just use the error handler, provided by `discord.py`, and print out the error with `str(error)` which should be different for every command/listener you use.

Comment: As I have said at more than five times, both edited in my question, and in multiple comments, I already have the error checking working. I am not going to remove the `discord.py` tag as my question is directly related to working with discord.py. I want to get the names of the arguments in the code as to create a formatted usage direction. To my knowledge the `error` object will not give me a list of these args.

Comment: Your comment, which you edited, said something different... My `on_command_error` answer does exactly what you want it to do or you are not expressing it correctly. Look again at my answer, but here only the first, non-existent argument is always spit out. Also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892141/discord-py-how-to-show-all-missing-parameters-in-a-command-in-the-global-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Command.signature](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.signature). This will automatically give you the usage of the command. Just use it in conjunction with the `on_command_error` and the `MissingRequiredArgument` error.

Example:

```
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.send(f"Correct Usage: {ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.name} {ctx.command.signature}")
```

This will return `Correct Usage: !test_command <arg1> <arg2>`

Comment: Is there a way to use this on commands that are not the current one? Taking commands from e.g. `bot.walk_commands()`, calling `.signature` gives an error because context is missing.

Comment: `signature` is an attribute of a `Command` object. You shouldn't need `ctx` for it to work. As for the case of `Bot.walk_commands`, you can iterate over the result and call `.signature` on it to get the `<arg> <arg2>`

Answer (score 1):

I see a few errors in your code which might stop the bot from working.

**First)** Why do you use `commands.Cog()`? It should be `client.command`/`commands.command`. The `commands` just inherite from `commands.Cog`

**Second)** The `reply` method is a bit deprecated. Instead we use `await ctx.send()`

Now, to include an error code you have to include your own handler for it.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@commands.Cog.listener
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        try:
            if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
                pass
            elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
                await ctx.send(str(error))
        except Exception as error:
            pass
```

This error handler informs you about the required arguments and mentions them.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Apologies; the`commands.command` typo is not in my code, I quickly typed this code for this question.
Concerning your answer, I already have the error checking logic in place.
In my question I am asking how to generate an automatic message containing the correct usage for the command, not hard coding the message like in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try except`

```
@commands.command()
async def test_command(self, ctx, arg1: str, arg2: int):
    try:
        msg = f"{arg1} and {arg2 + 5}"
        await ctx.reply(msg)
    except:
        await ctx.send('Correct usage: !test_command <arg1> <arg2>')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I already have the error checking logic in place.

My question is asking how to automatically generate the "Correct usage" message, and not hard-code it like in your answer.

Comment: I don't think there is automatic response, btw if you are using error handling you can do something like this `if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument): await ctx.send(error)` but it will send only the next missing parameter

Comment: I already have the error checking logic in place. My question is asking how to automatically generate a usage message, with the argument names included in said message. I am not looking for an automatic response, eg provided by discord.py. I am looking for a method to generate one myself. I have used automatic in this sense to mean procedural, ie not a hard-coded message.